# Triggering a build for a Jenkins Pipeline project when a commit is made on a specfic branch in Bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, webhooks

I currently have a Jenkins pipeline project that builds and tests some code. I want to be able to run this pipeline with all of my current build parameters when a commit is made on a specfic branch within bitbucket. The source code management tab is currently missing as this is a pipeline project. Any ideas for how I can go about this?

Currently I've installed the bitbucket plugin which shows the option of *Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket*. However, this does not allow me to specify which branch there needs to be a push to in order to start this build.

Comment: you could verify branch name inside your pipeline.  Also you could add a SCM step and set "Branches to build"  there.